# why write.xlsx2 does not store distinct spreadsheets?

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to save dataframes into distinct spreadsheets within an `.xlsx` document:

```
library(xlsx)

df1 <- data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "c"), b=c(3,4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(r=c(1,2,3), d=c("a", "b", "c"))

# append into corresponding spreadsheet

write.xlsx2(as.data.frame(df1),
            "path/dummy.xlsx",  
            sheetName = "TestSheet1", 
            col.names = T, 
            row.names = F, 
            append = F)


write.xlsx2(as.data.frame(df2),
            "path/dummy.xlsx",  
            sheetName = "TestSheet2", 
            col.names = T, 
            row.names = F, 
            append = F)
```

However, `write.xlsx2()` remove `"TestSheet1"`:

[image]

The idea is to have two distinct spreadsheets for two distinct dataframes, and if possible to append new data into the spreadsheets dataframes while keeping the same spreadsheets.

How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: do you need `append = TRUE`

Comment: Yes, it will be necessary to append new lines everytime the script is run

Comment: @akrun Care to post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just that the `append = FALSE` in both the cases thus it overwrites the whole file.  Change it to `TRUE` and it works.  Also, a good practise is to specify `TRUE/FALSE` instead of `T/F` as this can lead to errors (`F` is a function in `collapse`.  In addition, we could name objects with `T`, `F` whereas it cannot be done with `TRUE/FALSE`)

```
write.xlsx2(as.data.frame(df2),
            "path/dummy.xlsx",  
            sheetName = "TestSheet2", 
            col.names = TRUE, 
            row.names = FALSE, 
            append = TRUE)
```